# Suggestions to filter RF from a long wire connected to a logic gate

Tags: rf, passive-filter

The following is the schematic of a security system designed to work on the break-wire principle and intended to be used on a perimeter fence. The input 2 of logic gate U-3.1 is kept low via a long thin (60 ft) bifilar wire. Upon breakage of the wire, R4 makes the aforementioned input 1 high, which turns Q2 on. Although I have dedicated filter cap C2 (100nF ceramic) and ferrite bead on the break-wire near the circuit, Do you think that would be enough? Please post your suggestion to improve this filtering and to make this circuit more immune to false alarm induced by RF, EMI etc. The whole circuit board will be placed in an aluminium box except for the break-wire. The power source is 9v battery.
[image]
Kindest regards

Comment: With such high impedances CMOS IC, 3.3M pull-up you have created an antenna. IMO this circuit is designed to pick up noise rather than to reject it.

Comment: The CMOS was used because the circuit needs to operate on 9v battery for a long time.

Comment: I agree 3.3 M ohm on that line is asking for trouble, very likely it will pick up plenty of 50 or 60 Hz from the mains making the gates flip in random states. I'd start with lowering that 3 M ohm to 10 kohm or even 1 kohm ig you can live with the current which will flow.

Comment: The problem is the battery life would decrease significantly. Is there any way to remove these noise before reaching the input?

Comment: OK, when battery fed you the supply is floating, that helps. You might get away with that 3.3 M ohm then. I'd filter the node going to all the gates though but not like you suggest. Let me draw a circuit...

Comment: On a side note.... be aware, this type of wire is EASILY defeated with a simple jumper cable.

Comment: It would be hard actually, the whole board is sealed inside an aluminium box, only a thin (0.1mm) is accessible from outside which is hard to see.

Comment: Not that hard @Baphomet, if I want to cut through your fence, and notice the trip line, I only need to jumper across where I want to enter before making the cut. I don't have to trace it back to the box.

Comment: It is not on the fence itself, it's 20cm above the ground attached to sticks far apart camouflaged by grass. Like a landmine. believe me it is hard to see.

Comment: Regardless of whether connecting a long wire directly to the input of a CMOS gate is a good idea, the rest of the circuit is rubbish. What exactly do you think all of those gates are accomplishing?

Comment: Dear dave, before calling my design rubbish, please note that this is a working circuit and It has already been tested. If you need full schematic let me know. If you don't understand the function of circuit or part of it, don't call it rubbish.

Comment: OK, I guess "working" means something different from what I would normally expect in a perimeter alarm. But even if what it does is what you want it to do, it's still a lot of extra gates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make the tripwire input like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEuRcp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This way you keep the low quiescent current but improve the filtering. if the wire breaks.

Also: you can leave out the ferrite bead, it will not help to improve anything.

Comment: Could you please explain theory behind adding the extra resistor?

Comment: R2 and C1 make a lowpass filter. Previously you did not have R2 so anything picked up by the wire goes straight to the gates. Now the resistor provides a high impedance and C1 will provide a low impedance for high frequency signals. It is not that different from what you had only a bit more robust because of the extra R2.

Comment: Ok thanks, is the 100nF for C2 is optimum? also what do you think about adding an inductor or wire wound ferrite in series with breakwire?

Comment: Capacitor could be *much* bigger - unlikely that few seconds of delay would matter.

Comment: What is optimum ? Define your optimum. No that 100 nF is just a value which I suck out of my thumb, I can do that since I have **experience** and know that this will work. You can use 10 nF or 1 uF if you like but with 1 uF it will take a couple of seconds before a break is detected. So 100 nF is a good compromise. No, inductors or beads will not help, the capacitor alone is enough. You'd have to use a pretty large value inductor to be of significance here. And there's no need for an inductor.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to question your experience, I just asked if the value would be optimum for filtering maximum noises.

Comment: Also many 1 uF or larger capacitors can leak a bit of current, depending on their type and that will interfere with operation. 100 nF are nearly always ceramic caps and these don't have any significant leakage. Electrolytic caps often have leakage.

Comment: If you want "optimum" you have to define what is the "optimum" and do calculations, simulations and experiments. Will that make the circuit much better than using 100 nF ? Nope, but please prove me wrong if you like. It will just cost you a lot of time and effort. I was not offended because I mentioned **experience** :-) I'm just explaining that you should optimize where that gives benefit (like 3.3 Mohm for battery lifetime) but elsewhere a "best guess" value is good enough, no optimization needed. Experience helps in choosing: optimize / best guess.

Comment: No argue with you sir, you'r an expert. You are right, the 100nF is the best. Treveor has added some extra component to your circuit, what do you think?

Comment: I think that's overkill, not needed. But if you prefer the diode etc you can add that but in my opinion it does not make the circuit much better. Any transient signals on the tripwire cannot make it into the logic gates anyway because of the 3.3 M ohm series resistor (R2). I like keeping things simple :-)

Comment: Yup since it's battery powered it may well be @FakeMoustache. If it were plugged into the mains, discharge protection on a wire that length would be more of an issue.

Comment: Nearby lightning strikes might induce an *incredibly* large transient. Perhaps a 9v avalanche diode from junction of R1 & R2 to ground to absorb such a transient?

Comment: Such a diode is already implemented in Trevor's circuit above.

Comment: With lightning strikes I see only 2 situations: 1) the impact is small enough so that the circuit can handle it, in this case R2 and C1 and the ESD protection diodes in the CMOS logic gates take care of the pulse 2) the impact is such that the whole circuit is completely destroyed. When lightning **really** strikes the mains wires can be **blown out of your house's wall** there's no transorb able to prevent that ! You might expect miracles from transorbs, I have yet to see those miracles proven.

Comment: That's true @FakeMoustache, a full on strike and bye-bye box, but even a strike half a kilometer away can cause a lot of voltage in that wire due to ground conduction effects. BUt like I said earlier, being a battery box, gives the device some protection. I would not want to be holding it at the time though .

Comment: Lol I guess you'r right. BTW, does the value of R2 need to be same as R1?

Comment: *does the value of R2 need to be same as R2* No, another "best guess" since you had a 3.3 M ohm I added another one. If R2 is 1 M ohm or 10 Mohm the circuit will also work.

Comment: To rephrase the question, will increasing R2 reduce the transient signal in the tripwire?

Comment: You don't care what's on the wire.. only what makes it to the gate.

Comment: @Trevor Ok thanks, may I ask the function of R2 and R3? considering the thin long wire might already have such a resistance?

Comment: *considering the thin long wire might already have such a resistance?* I suggest you get a multimeter and measure that ! And also measure the resistance of many other household things like yourself (hold a probe in each hand) pots, pans, water, cola etc..  Just for fun and learning. Even a thin wire of a couple of **kilo**meters long will have **much** less resistance than that 3.3 M ohm resistor. So no, the wire will have **orders of maginitude (1000x - 100000x) less** resistance than that 3.3 Mohm resistor.

Comment: Sorry I think you misunderstood me, considering R2 and R3 are both 10 ohm and connected to such a long wire which has probably the same resistance, I'd like to know the reason they were included.

Comment: You are confusing your answers here. I added the small series resistors in MY answer  to provide a little extra resistance / protection should the transorb come into play @Baphomet. They have very little / zero effect on normal operation.

Comment: BTW: You say you are going to use a metal box. If you plan on grounding it and attaching the battery negative to the case, the protection devices are more important.

Comment: No actually the box is not grounded. It just to provide more shielding for EMI.

Answer (score 2):

3.3 MOhms - can't be serious! A drop of water bypasses your wire and nothing is detected. Change the pullup resistor to 500 Ohm. If that's too much in current consumption, consider to have pulsed operation -  say 1 ms in every half second.

No test? Again: Cant't be serious! You should have a relay that makes a test breakage somewhere, preferably in the middle of the loop and a checking plan, too, preferably automatic.

A lowpass RC filter at the input of your nand gate kills the RF, have a time constant 1...100ms.

Consider  more specific detection.  ON-OFF does not see the bypassing. At least make total bypassing difficult by keeping the outside ends of the loop unreachable at the same time.

ADDENDUM:

**The test relay**: A normally closed switch is inserted as a part of your loop. The switch is remotely controlled.The simplest form of it is a relay. If opening the switch does not cause alarm, the current has a bypass way somewhere (=a bypass circuit is inserted, broken insulations and the vire is in the water)

Before any further circuit analysis a threat analysis should be performed. The most important things after deciding that the intrusion trial is probable and a tripwire is useful:

- does the intruder know beforehand that there's a tripwire (=by having some inside knowledge)
- can the intruder survey freely the systems as long as he wants (=no dogs, no cameras, no motion sensors)
- if no foreknowledge, can the intruder see the tripwire before it's too late
- what's the workaround skill level of the intruder

I spotted word "**BIFILAR**" in your text. Your loop seems to have 2 parallel wires. Thus it can have 4 wire ends, all available where your electronics reside. See the illustration:

[image]

The bifilarity (=2 parallel identical wires) gives a lot of new possiblities that you should explore

- In heavy disturbing fields (=powerline, radio transmitters, high current works around) your system can feed the test voltage between the 2 wires. Any disturbing signal that affects equally to both wires can be cancelled
- If there appears a resistance difference  between the wires, something is added to the circuit
- if there appears a connection between the wires, something is added to the circuit
- a voltage or intentional signal between the wires can be used to do something useful. The wires can be at the same time for power supply, signal transmission and your original tripwire loop
- by measuring pulse reflections the place of the breakage can be deduced
  (not useful if the max distances are only a few meters, but very useful if the distance is beyond the field of the vision)

I have not written about how to protect against the lightning (not direct hit, but nearby). For that the methods can be borrowed from the landline telephony.

A way to reduce induced voltages - not much better than a twisted pair as a single wire loop and makes bypassing easy. Gathers common mode (=against the earth) voltages as easily as a single wire loop => NOT RECOMMENDED. To utilize properly the 4 end loop, you must have more complex circuit.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the solutions has been posted by Trevor and fakemoustache. Could you explain more on using relay?

Comment: All good points. Not sure the water drop is an issue though, unless it's right where the wires come together. I was assuming the wire was insulated out to some distance apart.

Comment: BTW : There is also a method to use the wire single or double  ended fed with either a pulse or continuous AC waveform / signal, and tracking the capacitance or inductance of the line. That type is very hard to defeat.

Comment: Do you have any schematics for this type? I think it is also known as 'ground sensor".

Comment: Not off hand no. Would probably involve a signal generator and tuned receiver that integrates the average return signal level and trips on a variance on that level.

Comment: There is a fibre-optic solution too.

Comment: I found one: https://www.google.com/patents/US3754508

Comment: I don't know it doesn't seem reliable, what if it rains? Or other environmental issues.

Comment: @Trevor would a 12v transorb diode be a good value?

Comment: If your powering it from 12V I'd go higher.

Comment: It's 9v. Does this type of diode has polarity? if yes I assume it's same as in you diagram.

Comment: @Trevor I've found two versions of TVS diodes, unidirectional and bidirectional, which one would be more suitable for this application?

Comment: @user287001 Thanks for the clarification. Regarding the test, the circuit has a feature where any breakage prior to arming delay( power on delay) e.g poor connection of break wire is detected. If the connection of BW is ok the green led is on otherwise it's off. This also prevent the timing capacitor to charge. The intruder can not know the location of tripwire as it's 20cm above the ground in the grass. By intruder I mostly mean animals as this device will be used for a camping site. Although it can be used against potential burglars also.

Comment: @user287001 please correct me if I am wrong. You'r saying by using bifilar wire instead of singular, attached to R3,R2 ( See Trevor's circuit) any induced voltage will be cancelled?

Comment: @Baphomet all the drawings in the other answers and your own schematic use single wire. It can be a sigular wire or a bifilar wire that has a short ciruit at the far end to make a single loop. To cancel the induced voltages the schematic must be different. All 4 ends must be available in the electronics box. Are they available?

Comment: As you said the original design uses bifilar that has short at far end. But, it can be easily changed, I'll connect A1,B1 in your diagram to R2 and A2,B2 to R3 ( Trevor's circuit), is that right?

Comment: @Baphomet connect A1 and B2 together. Then connect A2 and B1 together. Now you have single zero inductance loop that theoretically does not gather anything to Trevor's circuit between the R2 and R3. But a tightly twisted pair itself gathers very little, too between the wires, So the benefit can be marginal. What you should notice, is the induced voltage - not between the loop ends, but between the whole loop and the earth. Your circuit can in bad weather get a big voltage lift over the earth. That can make an arc at the weakest point. You need a grounding. 4-ends helps revealing the bypass.

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://i.imgsafe.org/323040a8b7.png

Comment: @user287001 the link is broken, use the website that i used for image hosting. So overall, to conclude this discussion you recommend the twisted pair shorted at end in the original design?

Comment: @Baphomet removed the comment and inserted the story + photo into my answer

Comment: Thank you for all your helps. Please feel free to share all your thoughts on further improving this design later, if you find spare time. Have a nice evening.

Answer (score 0):

Use a large value resistor tree, and put the capacitor on the same side as the pull-up not the ground side. It will take a little longer to switch, but not long enough to care about.

I'd also add series resistors and a protection diode as shown to give you some protection from static and maybe even a Transorb go give you some protection from static discharge, though it won't protect you from a lightning strike directly on the fence.

Both the ground side AND the signal side need to go through the bead with a turn or four. Though you may not need it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwL2tn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Trevor, the problem is circuit is operated by 9v battery and therefore need to have very low quiescent current.

Comment: Ok.. then combine my answer with @FakeMoustache's

Comment: Thank you, may I ask where the other ends of R2 and R3 are connected to?

Comment: That's the ends of your trip wire, or connector for same.

Comment: Yes you re right, may I ask what is the value of zener diode? considering the power supply is 9v.

Comment: It's not a zener it's a transob, could not find a symbol for that in the tool. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient-voltage-suppression_diode

Comment: Ok It is the first I see this component. In terms of functionality it would be similar to zener though, right?

Comment: You can think of it like a bidirectional zener.. that is... two zeners nose to nose.